# Filter and map a java stream at the same time

Tags: java, datetime, dictionary, filter, java-stream

I have a list of strings, each of which is represents a date.  I'd like to map this list into a list of DateTime objects; however, if any of the strings are invalid (throws an exception) I'd like to log an error but not add it to the final List. Is there a way to do both the filtering and mapping at the same time?

This is what I currently have:

```
List<String> dateStrs = ...;
dateStrs.stream().filter(s -> {
    try {
        dateTimeFormatter.parseDateTime(s);
        return true;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.error("Illegal format");
        return false;
    }
}.map(s -> {
    return dateTimeFormatter.parseDateTime(s);
}.collect(...);
```

Is there any way to do this so that I don't have to parseDateTime twice for each element?

Thanks

Answer (score 14):

To my opinion, it would be more idiomatically correct to use `flatMap` here:

```
dateStrs.stream().flatMap(s -> {
    try {
        return Stream.of(dateTimeFormatter.parseDateTime(s));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return Stream.empty();
    }
}).collect(...);
```

Here you can do everything in single operation.

Answer (score 5):

Updating for Java 9

Similar to Tagir's solution, you can map to an `Optional`, logging an error when the conversion fails to produce a value.  Then, using the new `Optional::stream` method, you can `flatMap` on the optional, removing the failed conversions (empty optionals) from the stream.

```
dateStrs.stream()
    .map(s -> {
        try {
            return Optional.of(dateTimeFormatter.parseDateTime(s));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("Illegal format: " + s);
            return Optional.empty();
        }
    })
    .flatMap(Optional::stream)
    .collect(...);
```

Answer (score 4):

Do the operations in the opposite order.

```
List<String> dateStrs = ...;
dateStrs.stream().map(s -> {
    try {
        return dateTimeFormatter.parseDateTime(s);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return null;
    }
}).filter(d -> d != null).collect(...);
```

(Too late I realize this is essentially the same as @wero but hopefully the code will make it clear.)

Answer (score 2):

You could first map the string to its parsed date. If you encounter a invalid date string, you log it and return null.

Then in a second step you filter for non null dates.

Comment: This is what I always do. You can do `.filter(java.util.Objects::nonNull)` after the map operation which, IMO, is also quite readable.